# I need the correct code to work with my tkinter drop down

Tags: tkinter, printing

I'm trying to print the selection input from a drop down as per my example.  I was able to have it print once and can't get it back. I messed something up or deleted a section of code by accident.  I'm a novice and 72.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
root.title("Start-Founder")
root.geometry("400x400")

def selected(event):
 myLabel = Label(root, text=clicked.get()).pack()

def comboclick(event):
 myLabel = Label(root, text=myCombo.get()).pack()

def show(event):
 Label = clicked.get
 Button = Label()
 print(event)
```

options = [
"Monday",
"Tuesday"]

```
 clicked = StringVar()
 clicked.set(options[0])

drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, *options, command=selected)
drop.pack(pady=20)

myCombo = ttk.Combobox(root, value=options)
myCombo.current(0)
myCombo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", comboclick)
myCombo.pack()

def close():
root.destroy()
root.quit()

Button(root, text= "close Window", font=("Calibri", 14, "bold"),         command=close).pack(pady=20)
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote parts of the code to make it more readable.  I believe this accomplishes your request.  This will grab the selected value from the combobox and print it.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def get_value():
    value = mycombo.get()
    mycombo.delete("0", tk.END)
    print(value)


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Start-Founder")
root.geometry("400x400")

options = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"]
clicked = tk.StringVar()
mycombo = ttk.Combobox(root, textvariable=clicked, value=options)
mycombo.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Select", command= get_value)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```